GIT repo size explosion - repo size grows much faster than combined size of commit patch files
I'm noticing that my GIT repository size (aggressively pruned, gc'd, repack'd) is increasing much faster than the combined size of the patch files for the same commits.

The repo:

files: .txt, .py, .json only
branch: 1
history: strictly linear
commits: each commit makes changes to 3~5 files with ~1k lines modified in total, patch file generated with format-patch for each single commit has a typical size of 10~100kb


The steps I attempted:

Use du -hs to check my copy of the initial repo (containing 2 commits), the .git folder has a size of ~400Mb

Make a fresh clone from remote server (the repo now has 535 commits). Use du to check the cloned repo size, the .git folder has grown to 1.9Gb

git reflog expire --expire=now --all, git gc --aggressive --prune=now didn't change anything (as expected)

git count-objects -v confirmed that the repo only contains 1 pack, and has 0 garbage

git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/*.idx | sort -k 3 -n | tail -5 returns with 5 files sized 10Mb ~ 100Mb and all of them were added in the initial commit and remained unchanged up to the newest commit


I tried using git format-patch to find out which commits caused the .git folder to balloon, but I had little success:

git format-patch HEAD~533..HEAD --output=tmp.patch gave me a tmp.patch file sized ~32Mb only.

git format-patch <sha>^1..<sha> --output=tmp1.patch for individual commits generated patch files sized ~10kb on average.


Hence I'm struggling to understand why the repo size would grow so rapidly as I would expect git to pack things up nicely. Does anyone know why this might be happening and how I can manage or reduce the repo's size growth?

It may be that you're blowing Git's compression window, 400MB on just one commit with just text seems kinda unusual. Try git -c core.compression=9 repack -adf --window 500 --window-memory 1G (or even 2G if you've got a reasonably beefy system), Hunt up the command, that will take a while to run and you only want to do it once a year or so at most but it should cut it down a lot. It gets the full linux history down to around 2.1G for me, for instance.  You do not want to do the f flag often, after doing it once wait until the space usage starts getting splodey again.

@jthill Thank you! The 400MB commit is the initial one where I added my source data files (in json format), all subsequent commits averaged ~10kb in size only (as I could see from generated patch files). May I ask what should I do if I would like to host my repo on some git service platform which doesn't allow me to specify the compression level? Currently I host my repo on gitlab, they do have a housekeeping option but it barely brings down my repo size...

Git's heavily tuned for "normal" source, the heuristics that work so well for that are going to be off-target for 400MB of data (in I don't see how many files) so you'd need a private gitlab instance or maybe talk to their customer support.  1.6G isn't really all that large, however well the repack I suggested works on your local repo it'll work that well on anybody's.   It sounds like your changes do better with rev-to-rev deltas, where programming-source histories do better with Git's defaults. Whoever's doing the packing, to make it work well, will have to tune the defaults.

@jthill I'm kind of worried about future commits and whether I would have to rerun the repack command often to keep the repo size in check. I wish I could get a general idea about why the repo ballooned - 1.2GB growth vs 32MB uncompressed patch file just seems so bizarre and I can't figure out what git is doing with such simple modifications (e.g. one typical commit adds ~500 lines to one file, removes ~500 lines from another file, and introduced maybe one new file ~5kb). Is there something I could read to better understand git's underlining mechanism? I would appreciate some suggestions.

I'm thinking maybe I could implement my own version-control in the dumbest way possible (for example, I would just concatenate all changes to one single text file similar to git's format-patch results) and force-push to re-write git remote every time so it contains only 1 commit, then I would practically have the same history information like I do now with this ever-ballooning repo, but the repo would stay less than <500Mb. But it's incomprehensible that git would be less efficient than such a rudimentary implementation, I must be missing something.

No, if I was going to work at finding the downsides of all the tradeoffs in Git's history compression setup, having commits with largeish numbers of multi-megabyte files making few and (relative to the file size) small changes in ways that keep the changed files far from their counterparts in a sequential history would hit all the ones I can think of. Git's much better than other vcs's at keeping programming-language source projects compact, try importing the linux history into any other vcs and see how fast that gets painful, Git's efficiency is the reason Microsoft picked it for Windows.

It's just the use cases are so different all its defaults are wrong for yours.  How'd the repack with the settings I suggested do?

@jthill It's been 2h40m on Counting objects: 100% (81885/81885), done. Delta compression using up to 2 threads... I don't quite understand the difference, from Git's perspective, between changing 100 lines of Python code and changing 100 lines of a JSON file. Would you be so kind as to give me some rough ideas? Most of the large files (>20MB) in my repo have remained unchanged since the initial commit, and all other files being updated in commits are ~10-100KB each. Should I move the static largeish files to a different repo? I doubt it would help though...

I didn't anticipate a 2-thread cpu, Hope it's done by now, sorry for tossing such a big hammer without checking.  Why exactly it's not finding good deltas has to be they're blowing its factory window limits but your total object count's smaller than a single linux snapshot so what exactly's going on baffles me too some.

@jthill After 5h30m the .git folder was shrunk down to only 420MB, which is smaller than my initial repo (~427MB)! Wow, that's amazing. And ~6h-ish doesn't seem too bad if I can get away with running this process perhaps once every 1k commits... Thank you! I tried using git-sizer to analyze my repo, could it be that it's badly structured? One folder contains 40k smallish json files and git-sizer warned me with maximum exclamation marks * Trees                   |           |                                | |   * Maximum entries      [3] |  40.4 k   | !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! |

git-sizer looks useful, I hadn't heard of it before, thanks! Yes, massive file counts in a single directory is going to interfere with git's delta hunter, you could put existing files in directories named for the first two bytes of a hash of their names.
